# WSO2 - Integration studio freezing on sequence save

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-integration-studio

I am using WSO2 integration studio to develop carbon applications, when i try to save a sequence, the save takes half a minute and the studio becomes in "not responding" state until the slow save is done. Should i change anything in the configuration of the studio to make it faster?

To note that i tried to update IntegrationStudio.ini to use:

```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

But the issue is not solved. Any hints?

Note: same issue when i switch from design tab to source tab.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the studio's cache by deleting the **.metadata** folder located in your user directory **(e.g., C:\Users<username>.metadata).**.

Maybe it help you

Comment: i dont have this folder, is there a different place than under users?

Comment: For Windows:


ProgramData: Check the C:\ProgramData\WSO2\IntegrationStudio folder. This folder stores shared data for all users on the system.

Specific User Installation: If you installed WSO2 Integration Studio for a specific user, the .metadata folder might be located within the installation directory of your user profile. For example, in C:\Users\<username>\WSO2\IntegrationStudio.

Comment: i have one under the workspace folder. Can it be it?